# Where to start with Deprecated: Directive 'safe_mode' on line 0 in Apache error logs

Tags: apache2, php-5.3, safe-mode, php-safe-mode

We are inundated with the entry:

Deprecated: Directive 'safe_mode' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0
Deprecated: Directive 'safe_mode' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0
Deprecated: Directive 'safe_mode' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0

in the apache2 error logs. But the bug doesn't seem to have any notable effect on our systems. It makes it very hard for us to diagnose actual problems and errors by overfilling our error logs.

None of the sysadmins I work with are aware of when the error started appearing or what software might be causing it.

We are using Apache/2.2.16 on Debian.

Edit: I have tracked the problem down to Froxlor adding per-user ini files, some of which have safe_mode enabled. There seems to be no way to disable safe_mode either globally in froxlor or per user and the froxlor manual has nothing. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Safe_mode is a PHP feature that has been depreciated in 5.3 and ultimately removed in 5.4. It is pointless and potentially dangerous and should not be used.

To turn it off go to your php.ini file and change

```
safe_mode = on
```

to

```
safe_mode = off
```

Restart apache and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but safemode is already off in all of php's ini configuration files.

Comment: Unfortunately, we still have the same problem after commenting out all of the directives relating to safemode.

Comment: I have tracked the problem down to Froxlor adding per-user ini files, some of which have safe_mode enabled. There seems to be no way to disable safe_mode either globally in froxlor or per user and the froxlor manual has nothing. Any help?